# grails url mapping for google ajax search

Tags: grails, url-mapping

This is probably a very simple problem but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

I need to redirect google requests for ajax generated code to return a html template for indexing

I have the following in my urlmappings.conf

```
"/?_escaped_fragment_=$id"(controller:"google",action:"getOfferDetails")
```

However if I enter mysite?_escaped_fragment_=200 in the browser the controller is not called

If however I enter mysite_escaped_fragment=200 the controller is called and the action executed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ash

Comment: When `?` is used in urlMapping the component is treated as optional, hence your url mapping defaults to `"/"` (root context). When you omit the `?` while hiting, it treats the rest a query string and successfully directs to the controller. Any particular reason you need `?` in the mapping?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I at least think I need it is because the url requested by google will be of the form mysite/?_escaped_fragment_=200 etc.

Comment: If you are referring [ajax crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification), you can see the parameter key is `_escaped_fragment_`. `?` is a notion used to append query string to base url.

Comment: hi ashley did my answer solved your problem? if so i like up votes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use '?' char in the route matching i.e. it will be ignored.
Use this filter instead (put this class in the config folder w/ fileName CrawlerFilters.groovy):

```
class CrawlerFilters {
 def filters = {
    google(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
            boolean isCrawler = webRequest.params._escaped_fragment_ != null
            if (isCrawler && !request._alreadyForwarded) {
                request._alreadyForwarded = true
                forward controller: 'google', action: 'getOfferDetails'

            }
        }
    }
 }`
```